# Typescript Converting objects date property to New Date()

Tags: typescript, date

I have a CurrentWeather Model that I am getting from localStorage and Parsing to an object.

```
export interface CurrentWeather {
    LocalObservationDateTime: Date;
    Latitude: string;
    Longitude: string;
    LocationKey: string;
    LocalizedName: string;
    PrimaryPostalCode: string;
    Temperature: number;
    RealFeelTemperature: number;
    WeatherText: string;
    UvIndex: number;
    UvIndexText: string;
}
const currentWeather: CurrentWeather = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentWeather'));
```

Once I have parsed it, I want to use the LocalObservationDateTime to get the hours. But getting error, "Cannot read property 'getHours' of undefined".

```
 var localHour = currentWeather.LocalObservationDateTime.getHours();
```

Saw somewhere that the Date needs to be new Date(). Tried this but is not working.

```
  const localDate: Date = new Date(currentWeather.LocalObservationDateTime);
  const localDateHour = localDate.getHours();
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to rename every property to have a lower case to be able to access the values.

```
export interface CurrentWeather {
    localObservationDateTime: Date;
    latitude: string;
    longitude: string;
    locationKey: string;
    localizedName: string;
    primaryPostalCode: string;
    temperature: number;
    realFeelTemperature: number;
    weatherText: string;
    uvIndex: number;
    uvIndexText: string;
}
```